# Smooth scrolling in Android applications

Tags: android, scroll, smoothing

I would like to add the smooth scrolling functionality into my application. 
i.e. I have a huge text and I want to scroll it automatically (like in book readers).

Could anyone offer any examples of smooth scrolling?

Answer (score 4):

Just put the view(s) you want to scroll inside a ScrollView. So to put some text in a scrolling area, put the text in a TextView, and then the TextView inside a ScrollView, like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/my_view_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks Ollie C, I did like you said, I can scroll the text, and I can see scrollbars, the question is how can I scroll it automatically. I'm trying to use scrollTo and ScrollView.scrollBy and ScrollView.scrollTo methods, but it is not working for me. Thanks

Comment: Ollie C, Also I added a button and I've tried to use scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, POSITION); It is working for me but scrooling is to fast, Can I override scrolling (or animation) settings or smth. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection to update the ScrollView's Scroller:

```
Field mScroller;
mScroller = ScrollView.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
mScroller.setAccessible(true);

CustomScroller scroller = new CustomScroller(getContext(), new AccelerateInterpolator());
mScroller.set(this, scroller);
```

Use smoothScrollTo method (may have to setSmoothScrolligEnabled(true))